# How to represent nested objects

Tags: prolog

I have recently been curious about Prolog and how it might be used to represent and query a more realistic dataset than the usual parent/child examples I see everywhere.

To play around, I generated a small dataset with the following structure:

```yaml
books:
  - titles:
      - My first book
      - My first attempt at a book
    authors:
      - firstname: Alice
        lastname: Ecila
      - firstname: Bob
        lastname: Obb
```

After few trials I ended-up with something looking like:

```
book(1).

title(book(1), "My first book").
title(book(1), "My first attempt at a book").

author(book(1)).

firstname(author(book(1)), "Alice").
firstname(author(book(1)), "Bob").

lastname(author(book(1)), "Ecila").
lastname(author(book(1)), "Obb").
```

This works pretty well to query information about the books but I lose completely the relationship between properties of the nested objects. There is no way, for example, to know the `lastname` of `Alice`. In an other hand if I try to represent books as a single term like this:

```
book(
  title("My first book"),
  author(
    firstname("Alice"),
    lastname("Ecila")
  )
).
book(
  title("My first book"),
  author(
    firstname("Bob"),
    lastname("Obb")
  )
).
book(
  title("My first attempt at a book"),
  author(
    firstname("Alice"),
    lastname("Ecila")
  )
).
book(
  title("My first attempt at a book"),
  author(
    firstname("Bob"),
    lastname("Obb")
  )
).
```

or this:

```
book(
  [ title("My first book"),
    title("My first attempt at a book")
  ],
  [ author(
      firstname("Alice"),
      lastname("Ecila")
    ),
    author(
      firstname("Bob"),
      lastname("Obb")
    )
  ]
).
```

I either lose a certain amount of information or it becomes too complex to query. Trees seem simple enough to represent but graphs in general appear to be more complicated.

So here is my question: what has been and/or is the preferred way to represent complex, nested objects in prolog?

I am also looking for samples and/or literature on this specific topic.

Comment: have you heard of relational databases? everything that applies to the design or relational data applies to Prolog basically 1:1. Only the query language is (much!) cleaner than SQL.

Comment: Do you mean that I am supposed to normalize and go through all the same artifices of RDBMSs like artificial primary keys and tables for many-to-many relationships?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I also don't like "artificial" (surrogate) primary keys, but sometimes they can be useful (and sometimes not).

Comment: A journey that will expand your thinking on this topic is to take JSON data from the wild and convert it to SWI-Prolog dictionaries and then consider taking parts of the data in the dictionary an breaking them down into relationships (think predicates) and see where that takes you. Then do the reverse taking the data from relationships (think predicates) converting it to SWI-Prolog dictionaries and converting that to JSON. This is done often to import/export data so worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Just put them in tables. For example:

```
book(1).

book_title(1, 'My first book').
book_title(1, 'My first attempt at a book').

book_author(1, 'Alice', 'Ecila').
book_author(1, 'Bob', 'Obb').

book_titles(B, Ts) :-
    bagof(title(T), book_title(B, T), Ts).

book_authors(B, As) :-
    bagof(author(firstname(X), lastname(Y)), book_author(B, X, Y), As).

book_titles_authors(B, book(B, Ts, As)) :-
    book_titles(B, Ts),
    book_authors(B, As).
```

As you see, you can actually compose queries in Prolog. I did it just to show that once you have the relational data, it is easy to query it and put it together, nested if you prefer.

```
?- book_titles_authors(1, Book).
Book = book(1,
            [title('My first attempt at a book'),
             title('My first book')
            ],
            [author(firstname('Alice'),
                    lastname('Ecila')),
             author(firstname('Bob'),
                    lastname('Obb'))
            ]).
```

---

Here are some differences between a typical RDBMS and vanilla Prolog:

- Columns within Prolog tables have positions, not names. You see that with firstname/lastname above.
- In Prolog, the order of results is well defined.
- Constraints and keys are not part of the language.
- In Prolog, it is an in-memory database.
- You do not have a query planner and optimizer.

Please keep in mind this is vanilla Prolog. As Prolog is a high-level, general-purpose programming language, you can implement any of those with some effort. Some features already exist as libraries.

The one huge advantage of Prolog as a query language is that it composes very well, unlike SQL.

Comment: It's a single book with an alternative title.
In the case of the title it's a 1-to-many relationship between book and title and in the case of book and author a many-to-many relationship. I understand that in my first example and in yours as well, the query is easy. Unfortunately when the author contains one page of additional properties and sometimes complex ones, it's impossible to search without knowing the order of all the terms in book_author/x or have getters for every single property.

Comment: "[..] somewhat well understood that you can use relational data design in Prolog to good effect."
Any reading material you could point me to?

Comment: @ITChap Any book on databases will do. I have memories of reading a book by a dude called Ullman but I don't think this matters too much.

Comment: @ITChap I edited the answer now since I initially completely missed your point.

Answer (score 1):

I like the tables-method, and would like to experiment with it - but for simplicity's sake I've mostly been using json-like representation, which is also nice for interacting directly with the "normal" world, when receiving and outputting data.

Once you have a tree-like structure with named fields in lists you can easily traverse it with queries like
member(person:Person, ObjectList),
member(firstname: Name, Person)

-if you have a tree like [person:[firstname: john, lastname:brandyson]]

So, traversing and extracting is easy (and so is creation), but modification/updating is a bit more tricky. I'm going to implement this in a project I'm working on soon, and then I plan to do it in a way similar to how values are updated in immutable.js, where you get a shallow:ish copy of the old tree, with only the new parts of data updated (except it probably will be a lot less well done :))

Ps - in many dialects of Prolog, JSON is a valid data structure as it is, and then you only have to make some nice predicates to traverse it/extract values from JSON in a comfy way :)

Comment: Would be faster if able to take advantage of Prolog's indexing: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex

Comment: Sounds good, but that requires putting the data in the in-memory database, right? I haven't done very much in that vein, but it sure sounds like it would be flexible!

Comment: The point is that you can have nested "objects", usually represented as compound terms. (Aside: lists are a good choice if you have an ordered collection of any number of objects; for everything else, just use compound terms!) But this is different from how you store the data. Nothing prevents you from taking the data and nesting it any way you want; but if you keep it nested, you must know the exact structure in order to query it.....

Comment: "So, traversing and extracting is easy (and so is creation)" yeah maybe if you have like one kind of object, one nesting level deep. Before you know it you are writing xpath queries and xslt transformations, and you are wondering when did it all go so wrong ;-)

Comment: TA: you are right about many things there. Maybe my method makes more sense when I clarify that I do know the exact structure - i have edit-time tools that work like intellisense, from schemas. No problems with deep structures or complex types :)